# Error redirecting to a custom URL protocol

Tags: windows, internet-explorer

In my post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795463/custom-url-protocol-in-windows-emailing-links), I made mention of having an issue with a custom URL protocol link being sent in an email. I got around that issue by sending a link to a web page, which then did the redirect to the custom URL protocol (presumably the issue with sending the direct link was that Gmail (and possibly other providers) were seeing my protocol as "unsafe" and therefore stripping it out of the email).

This is fine and dandy, *except* in IE8 (I'm unsure about IE7). If I go to that page in FF3 and Chrome, it opens my program as I would expect. In IE8, I just get a generic "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage" error. Does anyone have any idea why IE8 won't prompt me to run the program?

Comment: Just a guess but did you try and lower the security settings of IE8? Maybee add your site as trusted. Also is your program signed?

Comment: Just tried...none of those things helped. My app isn't signed, I don't think.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom protocol MVC Redirect working in Chrome but not IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30503802/custom-protocol-mvc-redirect-working-in-chrome-but-not-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Custom URL's are often considered dangerous or insecure content in the modern web universe. Your experience with gmail is an example. Many browsers have designs that limit or block URL schemes they do not recognize. The error page might be IE8's default behavior. I have not had much luck with researching my IE8-specific issues, so someone else will probably have to fill in the blanks. (Wiki flag is ON).

Comment: I keep looking at Apple's iTunes links as the example...I can go to this page: http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=309080428&mt=8 in IE, and I get the behavior I'd expect. I do notice that I have an iTunes detector add-on or something for IE...would I have to write something similar for my own app?

Comment: Also of note is that if I create a regular page that has a link of my custom type, browse to that page in IE and click on the link, it works fine...but the auto-redirect does not. Maybe I can just add behavior to my page to display the link if the browser is IE.