# Custom protocol MVC Redirect working in Chrome but not IE

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have an ActionResult that returns a redirect:

```
        public ActionResult TeamviewerConnect(int id)
        {
          snipped ...
            return Redirect("impacttv://" + Endpoint.tbl_computerinfo.FirstOrDefault().teamviewerID + "::" + teamviewerPassword);
        }
```

impacttv:// is a custom protocol and works fine in both IE and Chrome as a standard link.

This works fine in Chrome, but 404s in IE - anyone have an idea?

Comment: Can you actually see the correct Uri in the address bar of IE?

Comment: I see the address to my controller / action, which is correct but not the URL as specified by the Redirect, so it is hitting the controller/action but not doing the redirect.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/798629/error-redirecting-to-a-custom-url-protocol . This says that IE cannot do this. My best advice would be to create a special view for your redirect and have either a meta redirect or use javascript to set the `window.location`

Comment: Hmm yes it appears this is because it is a custom protocol, god damn it IE! Always bloody IE... If you convert to an answer I shall mark as answered :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See: [Error redirecting to a custom URL protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/798629/error-redirecting-to-a-custom-url-protocol).

> I know this has been a while since you asked, but [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/07/14/url-protocols-application-protocols-and-asynchronous-pluggable-protocols-oh-my.aspx)
>   describes the redirect behaviour for custom protocols.
>
> The bad news is that redirects don't work for IE.

This says that IE cannot do this. My best advice would be to create a special view for your redirect and have either a meta redirect or use JavaScript to set the `window.location`.

The other option is to do the initial call as a MVC WebApi AJAX method, return the Uri and then set the location so that the user does not navigate away from the 'starting' page. I have used this last method before and can confirm that it definitely works.

### MVC WebApi

You need to get the Mvc WebApi nuget package installed and probably a few others that I can't remember off the top of my head :p

**TvController.cs**

```
public class TVController: ApiController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public string TeamviewerConnectUri(int id)
    {
        return "impacttv://" + Endpoint.tbl_computerinfo.FirstOrDefault().teamviewerID + "::" + teamviewerPassword;
    }
}
```

**JS (using jQuery as it is included by default in an MVC project)**

```
var apiUrl = '/api/tv/TeamviewerConnectUri';

$.get(apiUrl, {id: 1 })
    .then(function(uri)) {
        window.location = uri;
        // window.open(uri);
    });
```

### Standard MVC Way

**TvController.cs**

```
public class TVController: ApiController 
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TeamviewerConnectUri(int id)
    {
        return Json(new {uri = "impacttv://" + Endpoint.tbl_computerinfo.FirstOrDefault().teamviewerID + "::" + teamviewerPassword}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**JS (using jQuery as it is included by default in an MVC project)**

```
var apiUrl = '/tv/TeamviewerConnectUri';

$.get(apiUrl, {id: 1 })
    .then(function(data)) {
        window.location = data.uri;
        // window.open(data.uri);
    });
```

Comment: Michael, do you have any example of the latter?

Comment: See my edit mate, you'll have to have a quick google about how to set up web api nicely - there is tonnes out there.. I usually create an `api` folder in the controllers folder.. there will be a separate file in the `App_Start` folder for the WebApi Routes

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, wouldn't it be possible to use a normal Controller Action which returns URL as string in JSON result, then there would be no need for WebAPI? What do you think?

Comment: @ManikArora That is true, but the WebApi framework is built exactly for this kind of thing, you can basically return any object from it and it will serialize it based on what serializer you have implemented. I am pretty sure it also doesn't load the whole MVC framework too so it is fast as..

Comment: I'm not sure what the best method is to use, I need the user to stay on their original page when they click the link that initiates the action. With that in mind, what would be the best options?

Comment: @MichaelCoxon, You're absolutely correct the WebAPI has some performance gains but that would be very minimum for this case, as it just needs to pass url as string, So for the OP, if he intends to use webapi further more in this project he should definitely choose WebAPI way or else if he needs to add WebAPI only for this requirement then he should choose the other way it will help him to keep his project managed in more simple way. :)

Comment: Either will work. I provided the WebApi one because I know it does work. But returning a `JsonResult` from your normal controller would work the same way. The other thing to consider is if you can use WebApi for some of your other methods.. It is better for maintainability if you use the WebApi for all AJAX requests, as they will always be in one location and not spread throughout your controllers.

Comment: @ManikArora +1, that's almost what I just said haha.. but you are right, if it is just this one action you need as an AJAX request - put it in your normal controller.. will add this too my answer as well..

Comment: +1 Haha yes, that's the same thing I mentioned, if there are more similar stuff to do then definitely should choose WebAPI or else should keep it simple. Simple code is definitely the best thing to maintain. I think your answer would be helpful to the OP :)